# Disable user profile edit?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

How do I stop registered users from changing their details like their username etc (via edit profile) in the frontend?

Comment: I can't see where this is set in permissions? I have set "Frontend User Parameters" to Hide, but nothing else lets me disable this feature that I can see..

Comment: Try with "Edit own" for registered users

Comment: I've just checked and all of the permissions for the group is set to "Not Allowed"

Comment: Maybe creating a menu item for that page and then restricting access to it.

Answer (score 2):

open `components\com_users\models\forms\profile.xml` and then edit:

```
<field name="password1" type="password"
  readonly="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can at the 'disabled attribute to the input fields u don't want to be changed.
Most of the users won't fiddle around with you page's source code.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would however like to disable it and not hide it, if possible though :).

Comment: This will not hide it, it will disable it, thus not letting the user to change the value of the input field

Comment: depends on the component u're using. This should help you to understand how to override joomla components without the need of 'hacking' the core files: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite familiar with overrides already, but setting the fields as disabled still loads the page. The best way I have found would be to to a manual redirect to a desired page.